# Visual Studio Code Zip File editing

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a plugin to directly edit content of a zip file without extracting the content to a temporary folder myself ?

I have already tried the Zip File Explorer Plugin, but it is a read only viewer.

Comment: Any plugin is still going to extract the files, then replace them after you save.  You just need a plugin that does it automatically?

Comment: Of course it has to extract. It will not inject binary content. I am asking from a user perspective, if there is any solution / plugin. Not from technical perspective :-)

Comment: [Zipadee](http://zipadee.now.sh) uses the VS Code editor (Monaco) for editing the contents of ZIP files - maybe useful, even if it's not exactly what you're looking for.